# Optimization: Farming wheat and rice

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

**This is the problem statement**

An Indian farmer has a piece of farmland, say $L$ square kilometres long, and wants to either sow wheat or rice or a combination of both. The farmer has a limited amount of $F$ kg of fertilizer and $P$ kg of insecticides.

Every square kilometre of wheat requires $F1$ Kg of fertilizer and $P1$ Kg of insecticide. Every square kilometre of rice farming requires $F2$ Kg of fertilizer and $P2$ Kg of insecticide. Let $S1$ be the price obtained by selling wheat harvested from a square kilometre and $S2$ be the price obtained by selling rice harvested from a square kilometre.

You have to find the maximum total profit that the farmer can earn by selecting the area in which wheat and/or rice should be farmed.

For example:

> $L = 10 Km^2 , F = 10 Kg, P = 5 Kg, F1 = 2 Kg, P1 = 2 Kg, F2 = 3 Kg, P2
> > = 1 Kg, S1 = 14 , S2 = 25$.

In this case, the farmer will earn a maximum profit if he sows only Rice on $3.33 Km^2$ area and maximum profit value will be $83.33$.

**Input Format**

The only of input will consist of $9$ integers space-separated, $L, F, P, F1, P1, F2, P2, S1, S2$

**Constraints**

```
1 <= L <= 10^4
1 <= F <= 10^4
1 <= P <= 10^4
F1 + F2< = F
P1 + P2 <= P
1 <= S1 <= 10^4
1 <= S2 <= 10^4
```

**Output Format**

Output will be

- Maximum profit correct up-to 2 digits
- value in km 2 where wheat should be planted correct up-to 2 digits
- value in km 2 where rice should be planted correct up-to 2 digits . For the example considered in the question output will be $83.33$ $0.00$ $3.33$ .

**Sample Test Case**

**Input**

```
10 10 5 2 2 3 1 14 25
```

**Output**

```
83.33 0.00 3.33
```

**Explanation**

let us say that $L = 10 Km^2 , F = 10 Kg, P = 5 Kg, F1 = 2 Kg, P1 = 2 Kg, F2 = 3 Kg, P2 = 1 Kg, S1 = 14 , S2 = 25$ . Total profit will be maximum if farmer does not plant any wheat but plants rice on $3.33 Km^2$ area and maximum profit value is 83.33 .

[image]

I require a solution to this problem. However, unable to grasp the statement itself. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Just a heads up there are a lot of pure mathematicians here and they don't seem to take well to applied maths, especially things like mathematical economics which may not be in their sweet spot.  Do you have a copy of Chiang? https://www.amazon.co.uk/Chiang-Fundamental-Methods-Mathematical-Economics/dp/B00NBCYWT4